# .htaccess rewrite when site has multiple domains

Tags: domains, htaccess, multiple-domains

I run a university club website which has <del>two</del> three (update: I have recently discovered the third) domains, let's say `www.meow.co.uk`, `foo.uni.ac.uk/bar/meow/` and `uni.ac.uk/bar/meow`. I'm using the following `.htaccess` in the folder `foo.uni.ac.uk/bar/meow/` in order to remove ".html" from the pages.

```
#meow.co.uk/page will display the contents of meow.com/page.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]

#302 from meow.co.uk/page.html to meow.com/page
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=302,L]
```

This works fine on `www.meow.co.uk/page.html --> www.meow.co.uk/page` but for the other domain, it treats `foo.uni.ac.uk/` as the root directory, so `foo.uni.ac.uk/bar/meow/page.html --> foo.uni.ac.uk/page`. I want it to go to `--> foo.uni.ac.uk/bar/meow/page`.

How can I modify the htaccess file so that it works for both domains? Or failing that how can I redirect from `foo.uni.ac.uk/bar/meow` to `www.meow.co.uk`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=302,L]`

The problem is that for `www.meow.co.uk` you need to redirect to `/$1` (as above) and for `foo.uni.ac.uk` you need to redirect to `/bar/meow/$1`. I don't think there is an immediate way around that.

However, you could conditionally set an environment variable (eg. `BASE_URL`) to the value of the required base URL for the redirect depending on the value of the `Host`. And use this environment variable in the `RewriteRule` directive.

For example, at the top of your script, set the environment variable:

```
SetEnvIf Host "foo\.uni\.ac\.uk" BASE_URL=/bar/meow
```

When the site is accessed via `www.meow.co.uk` then `BASE_URL` will not be set (ie. it's empty).

Then, change your `RewriteRule` substitution to use this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ %{ENV:BASE_URL}/$1 [R=302,L]
```

You should change the `302` (temporary) redirect to a `301` (permanent) redirect when you have confirmed it's working OK.

---

**UPDATE:** However, you are better off canonicalizing the URL and redirecting to the canonical domain (ie. `www.meow.co.uk`). With three different domains you have a lot of potential duplicate content. So, instead of the above, simply redirect to the canonical domain at the top of your script:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.meow.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^bar/meow/(.*) http://www.meow.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

---

Just to clarify... you have already changed the URLs on your site to use the extension-less version and this redirect is only required for old URLs that might have been indexed, shared, etc. Yes?

Comment: Actually, I haven't changed the URLs in my anchors to remove the .html extension - what is the reason for doing so? When I'm testing the website on my local drive, those anchors wouldn't work if I did that

Comment: If you don't change the URLs on your site then every time a user clicks a link they will be redirected - 2 requests to your server. You would need to install a webserver locally to test.

Comment: I've updated my answer... in order to avoid "duplicate content" (particularly with 3 domains) you are better off redirecting to the canonical URL.

Comment: The rule in your update doesn't work for me. When I navigate to `https://foo.uni.ac.uk/bar/meow/page/` it redirects to `https://foo.uni.ac.uk/http://www.meow.co.uk/page/`

Comment: I figured out this is due to a later rule `
#remove trailing slash if not a directory`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`
`RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=302]` But I don't know why

Comment: The above (canonical) redirect should go at the top of your script. If it's at the top then mod_rewrite directives that follow should not affect this. Note that for external redirects (eg. `[R=302]`) you probably should include the `L` flag as well. Also, external redirects should generally come before internal rewrites (so, your original two rulesets in your question should be reversed).

Comment: But what if a user navigates to `foo.uni.ac.uk/bar/meow/page/`? (Page is a html file) I want to redirect to `meow.co.uk/page/` and then remove the trailing slash, unless it would be better to do both at the same time. But I also want `meow.co.uk/page/` to show the contents of `meow.co.uk/page.html`

Comment: (I'm using 302s until I can get htaccess to behave the way I want. Using 301s is risky as they will be aggressively cached)

Comment: Ah yes sorry, just overlooked the `/bar/meow/` path on the other domains. That just requires a small change on the `RewriteRule`. I've updated my answer. I would leave the "slash removal" to your existing directive (if it is required at all), they need to be separate anyway.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the ticket either... I'm going to open another question about this, as I think it's another matter